# How to change aspect ratio of Game View using c# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

> How can I change the `GameWindow` aspect ratio using C# within the `Unity editor`

**Like this:**

[image: Example]

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using reflection:

```
public static void ChangeResolution(int sizeIndex)
{
    var assembly = typeof(Editor).Assembly;
    var gameView = assembly.GetType("UnityEditor.GameView");
    var instance = EditorWindow.GetWindow(gameView);
    gameView.GetMethod("SizeSelectionCallback")!.Invoke(instance, new object[] { sizeIndex, null });
}
```

`sizeIndex` is the index of the resolution in dropdown (0 - free aspect; 1 - 800x480)